# How to resolve this "A different connection with alias `default` was already registered"

Tags: disconnect

File "C:\Users\Admin\iwo-core\venv\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\connection.py", line 426, in connect
raise ConnectionFailure(err_msg)
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: A different connection with alias `default` was already registered. Use disconnect() first

Comment: Hi there, please provide more details about your issue for further discussion

Comment: ((venv) C:\Users\Admin\iwo-core>python run.py)--When i running like this i got error like this  -- File "C:\Users\Admin\iwo-core\venv\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\connection.py", line 427, in connect
    raise ConnectionFailure(err_msg)
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: A different connection with alias `default` was already registered. Use disconnect() first

Comment: Is this related to MongoEngine library? if so , please update your question tag accordingly, please update your post as well,  by briefly explaining "What you were trying to achieve~", after that show the error message. By following above mentioned, your post can attract more readers, and you'll find your desired solution sooner. Now it's not so clear for viewers. Best regards